# Azure list blob operation is failing with error 403 "AuthenticationError"

Tags: c++, rest, azure, curl

We are working on product which uses Azure storage service for storing data.

We are using Azure REST API through C++ to communicate with Azure. We are using cURL to execute REST request.

## Right now, we are working on functionality to list blobs, but its failing with error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate
 the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:16cd7e3d-0001-0032-2dd6-6f2e4f000000
Time:2016-02-25T14:14:23.2377982Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'CyPhz
sBdBCRRg2w157IYY4sIB23XwzKsfdAaUTVCAts=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign
: 'GET











x-ms-date:Thu, 25 Feb 2016 14:16:20 GMT
x-ms-version:2015-02-21
/sevenstars/container2
comp:list
delimiter:/
maxresults:2
restype:container'
</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
```

======================
Following is the wireshark output that we observed

```
GET /container2?comp=list&delimiter=/&maxresults=2&restype=container HTTP/1.1
Host: sevenstars.blob.core.windows.net
Accept: */*
x-ms-date:Thu, 25 Feb 2016 14:16:20 GMT
x-ms-version:2015-02-21
Authorization:SharedKey sevenstars:CyPhzsBdBCRRg2w157IYY4sIB23XwzKsfdAaUTVCAts=

HTTP/1.1 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
Content-Length: 704
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 16cd7e3d-0001-0032-2dd6-6f2e4f000000
Date: Thu, 25 Feb 2016 14:14:22 GMT

...<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:16cd7e3d-0001-0032-2dd6-6f2e4f000000
Time:2016-02-25T14:14:23.2377982Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'CyPhzsBdBCRRg2w157IYY4sIB23XwzKsfdAaUTVCAts=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET
```

======================

As per suggestions on Microsoft forum. I ensured all parameters are set correctly. (: is used instead of = in string to sign)

Can you please let us know that how can we resolve this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks and regards
Rahul Naik

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: How did you construct your SharedKey? Did you follow the instruction described in "[Authentication for the Azure Storage Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx)"?